# Android converting of file to bitmap returns null always

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have an existing `File` in my application and I want convert it to `Bitmap` with options. I have a method for that. But always this method returns null and when I try get properties of bitmap I catch `NullPointerException`. Here's a code:

```
public static Bitmap convertToBitmap(File file) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
}
```

If I remove options and call `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath())` I'll get `OutOfMemoryError` on some devices. What can I do with that?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code :)

```
    final Uri uri= Uri.fromFile(new File(file))
    try{
        Bitmap selectedImageBitMap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
        //you have your image bitmap :)
      }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException){
        Log.d("sandeep","could not find file");
      }
    catch(IOException ioexception) {
        Log.d("sandeep", "IOException");
      }
```

Lemme know if you still have issue :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for helping. But, unfortunately, I've catch OutOfMemoryError :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
bitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
```